# apache mod_proxy_html on Ubuntu ProxyHTMLEnable not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to use mod_proxy_html on Ubuntu which I installed from apt-get.  The module is loading properly and all ProxyHTML* directives work except for the one that matters the most.  When I do "ProxyHTMLEnable on" in my apache2.conf or vhost conf files, apache complains that it's an invalid directive and I must have misspelled it.  Is anyone else having this issue on Ubuntu and what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried leaving out "ProxyHTMLEnable on" entirely? I think that directive is new and not in the version in Ubuntu.

Do put "SetOutputFilter proxy-html" in its place

Comment: Thanks, you're a doll. Wish they included this in the docs for pre-3.1 users!!! :(

Answer (score 9):

While this isn't necessarily specific to the question, I figured I'd throw this out there for anyone else getting here from the Google super-highway.

I tried just removing the `ProxyHTMLEnable On` and adding `SetOuputFilter proxy-html`, but still wasn't working for me.  The "gotcha" in my case was the content mod_proxy_html was trying to process was compressed.

Adding `SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE` instead of `SetOuputFilter proxy-html` did it for me.  (will obviously lead to more processing being done)

This site explains it much better than I can:  http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Reverse_Proxy_Server_2:_mod_proxy_html_2#Cause_and_Solution_3

Comment: After hours of searching and debugging, this was a lifesaver. Thanks!

Comment: You're a genius. This works for for my version of mod_proxy_html Version: 3.0.1-1.1